# How to remove Parallel::Forkmanager from my Perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, parallel-processing

I have been out of the coding game for a couple of years and I do not have experience with Perl. I have a Perl script that I am trying to get through, but part of it is based on `Parallel::Forkmanager`.

At the moment I do not need this, but I do not know the language of Perl well enough to transform this part of my code into something where it does not rely on `Parallel::Forkmanager`, even though the answer is probably very simple.

PS: I could leave it in, but somehow I cannot get `Parallel::Forkmanager` installed correctly either, even with the advice given by many of you on different threads of this forum and other fora... But that would be another question. For now I am just trying to understand basic Perl.

````
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;    <- so this is what I do not want


#From Dummyset:
my @samples = ("F1_A_S383_L007", "F1_B_S384_L007");

print "Processing " . scalar(@samples) . " samples\n";


### Trim adapters
unless (-d "skewer") {
    mkdir "skewer";
}

my @skewerCommands;
foreach my $sample (@samples) {
    my $R1 = "reads/" . $sample . "_R1_001.fastq.gz";
    my $R2 = "reads/" . $sample . "_R2_001.fastq.gz";

    my $adapterFile = "universal.adapters";

    # Make sure the adapter file exists
    unless (-e $adapterFile) {die "$adapterFile not present!\n";}

    my $skewerBaseName = "skewer/" . $sample;

    push(@skewerCommands, "<right_path_to>/skewer-0.2.2/skewer --quiet -x $adapterFile -m pe $R1 $R2 -L 150 -e -z -o $skewerBaseName");
}
#print "Running all skewer commands\n";
my $skewerFM = Parallel::ForkManager->new(46);    #this is where I do not know a solution
foreach my $skewerCommand(@skewerCommands) {
    $skewerFM->start and next;
#    print "Running the following command: \n$skewerCommand\n";
 #   system($skewerCommand);
    $skewerFM->finish;
}
$skewerFM->wait_all_children();
#print "Finished running all skewer commands\n";  ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parallel::Forkmanager` is a parallelism option. It was probably put in to significantly accelerate this code's running, and by taking it out again - you might regret it.

However - the core part that's running in parallel is here:

```
my $skewerFM = Parallel::ForkManager->new(46);    #this is where I do not know a solution
foreach my $skewerCommand(@skewerCommands) {
    $skewerFM->start and next;
#    print "Running the following command: \n$skewerCommand\n";
 #   system($skewerCommand);
    $skewerFM->finish;
}
$skewerFM->wait_all_children();
```

You instantiate a forkmanager. You run code between 'start' and 'finish'. And then you wait for everything to finish.

Between `start` and `finish` - you don't actually do anything, because it's commented out.

So just delete that whole block, and the `use Parallel::ForkManager;` line, and you'll be fine.

Although, you *might* want to figure out what `$skewerCommand` is for, why it was running before, and why it *isn't* running now.

Because without that, you've basically made your entire code redundant.

If however, that's *not* meant to be commented, you can just excise these lines:

```
my $skewerFM = Parallel::ForkManager->new(46);    #this is where I do not know a solution
    $skewerFM->start and next;
    $skewerFM->finish;
$skewerFM->wait_all_children();
```

(And the initial `use` line).

Then your code will iterate each row in `@skewerCommands` and run the `system` command on each of them - but will do it serially, rather than 46 ways in parallel. (So you can expect it to be WAY slower).